# npm build creates d.ts files for all ts files. How to stop this?

Tags: typescript, npm

I'm building a simple npm package in typescript. When `npm build`, d.ts files are created for all ts files.

But I created a `types.ts` so is there any to stop npm from creating all those d.ts files?

`src/`:

```
index.ts
constants.ts
types.ts // all types are defined here
```

current `dist/`:

```
index.js
index.d.ts
constants.js
constants.d.ts
types.js
types.d.ts
```

wanted `dist/`:

```
index.js
constants.js
types.d.ts
```